# Time complexity for the following for Largest in array of unsorted numbers

Tags: java

Can anyone help to analyze the time complexity of this can and please explain why.
    I'm comparing the array elements with each other with one being max.
    I'm not sure how to calculate the time complexity for this.
    Can anyone help me with this?

```
 class Largest
 {
     public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
    int array[] = {33,55,13,46,87,42,10,34};
    int max = array[0]; // Assume array[0] to be the max for time-being

    for( int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) // Iterate through the First Index and compare with max
    {
        if( max < array[i])
        {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Largest is: "+ max);
 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

It is **O(n)**

```
//loop n-1 times, O(n)
for( int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) // Iterate through the First Index and compare with max
{
    //one comparison operation, O(1)
    if( max < array[i])
    {
        //one assignment operation, O(1)
        max = array[i];
    }
}
```

You do 2 constant operations, n-1 times.

O(n) * [O(1) + O(1)] = **O(n)**

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: yes, it's pretty clear now. Are there any ways to improve this code

Comment: why looping n-1 times gives O(n)?

Comment: Depends. You can sort it, which costs you O(n * logn), which is a higher cost, but you only need to do it once, and then checking the max value is as easy as looking at the first element.

Comment: See this article, scan to the part labeled O(n) https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Answer (score 0):

You loop goes around `n - 1` times so the complexity is `O(n)`